# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in Mapping code

Tags: hadoop

the input is `1000:rohit:male:dev:2500`

In this i want to count the male and female count. when i use split, assigning each gender field to reducer shows `ArrayIndexOutOfBounfException:2`

```
public class DeptEmpcountMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)

            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String st = value.toString();

        String[] field = st.split(":");
        String st1 = field[2];

        context.write(new Text(st1), new LongWritable(1));
    }

}
```

Comment: You say the reducer is throwing an exception but you have posted your mapper's code.

Answer (score 1):

You're making the dangerous assumption that every input record takes the form `1000:rohit:male:dev:2500`. From your error, it's clear that isn't the case. Bad data is always something that needs to be accounted for.

Consider some simple validation of your input beforehand:

```
String[] field = st.split(":");
if(ArrayUtils.getLength(field) == 5) {
    String st1 = field[2];
    context.write(new Text(st1), new LongWritable(1));
} else {
    //Consider printing "st" to see what the bad input looks like
}
```

Comment: But I think  the OP has specified that the input, specifically, is `1000:rohit:male:dev:2500` or maybe I'm interpreting it incorrectly. Nevertheless, helpful answer.